# Why won't Gurdurr evolve in conquest?

Tags: pokemon-conquest

I want all of my Pokemon evolve for my battle with Nobunaga. I looked at an evolution guide and it told me to have link at 60%, and have the final hit on a warrior's Pokemon. I already had the link at 60%, and I went into battle and defeated a warlord. But the Gurdurr still won't evolve. What do I do?